# Php image resize in output

Tags: php, html, image

I have this php function to resize image according to where i need it and the size i wish to display.
But my problem is how to i set it to display resized image in html image element without setting the php content type to image?
If i set content type to image it will display the image in the whole page and if i remove it it will output long unknown characters, how do i do this to get what i want?

```
    <?php
    function CroppedThumbnail($imagename, $imgwidth, $imgheight){
// Set a maximum height and width
$width = $imgwidth;
$height = $imgheight;
// Content type
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imagename);
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}
// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, $imagename, 100);
return $imagename;
}

$filename1 = 'http://static1.techlosofy.com/wp-content/uploads/YouTube-Logo-Large.jpg';
$filename2 = 'http://static1.techlosofy.com/wp-content/uploads/YouTube-Logo-Small.jpg';
echo '<img data="image1" src="'.CroppedThumbnail($filename1, 100, 100).'"/>';
echo '<img data="image2" src="'.CroppedThumbnail($filename2, 100, 100).'"/>';
    ?>
```

I want to resize any image that i call this function on

Comment: imagejpeg returns a boolean, true or false. You have to use the second parameter as the filename and return the filename and path.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer I did understand what the filename path you ask me to return

Comment: You did or you didn't? Well, you would need the actual created file to use in source for the img. In your case you currently get the whole image stream because of the second paraemter null.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer I did `return imagejpeg($image_p, $imagename, 100);` but i get this error The image “example.com/test.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors. Can you please show me a code example in answer?

Comment: @StuartBrian Use the header content-type= image also check whether there should not any output before image content. The error you are getting is because there is some output before image content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newFile = 'images/newFile.jpg';

imagejpeg($image_p, $newFile, 100);

return '/' . $newFile;
```

I have edited your code:

```
<?php
function CroppedThumbnail($imagename, $imgwidth, $imgheight){
// Set a maximum height and width
    $width = $imgwidth;
    $height = $imgheight;
// Content type
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Get new dimensions
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imagename);
    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
    if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
    }
// Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// Output
    $newFileName = 'images/newFile.jpg';
    imagejpeg($image_p, $newFileName, 100);

    return '/' . $newFileName;
}
$filename1 = 'http://static1.techlosofy.com/wp-content/uploads/YouTube-Logo-Large.jpg';
echo '<img data="image1" src="'.CroppedThumbnail($filename1, 100, 100).'"/>';
?>
```

Comment: in did this but the output image is large again

Comment: Sorry i removed other output before the code and content type and the output image is large again

Comment: i have update it, is returning the image name i want to output not the re sampled image

Comment: Because you are not using the cropped image yet, you are returning the original one. Look at my example!

Comment: Nice it created new image is okay

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an simple change to your code which will fulfill your requirement as well as will be reusable one.

Here we can separate resize functionality into separate file.

resize.php

```
<?php
 function CroppedThumbnail($imagename, $imgwidth, $imgheight){

 // Set a maximum height and width
    $width = $imgwidth;
    $height = $imgheight;

// Get new dimensions
   list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imagename);
   $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

   if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
     $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
   } else {
     $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
   }

 // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,  $width_orig, $height_orig);

   // Output
   return imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
}

  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  echo CroppedThumbnail($_GET['imagename'], $_GET['width'], $_GET['height'])
?>
```

Now we can use above resize file to render resized image by passing image name,height and width by into request.
example.php

```
 <?php
    $filename1 = 'path and file name of image 1 here';
    $filename2 = 'path and file name of image 2 here';

    echo '<img data="image1" src="imagetest.php?imagename='. $filename1 .'&height=100&width=100"/>';
    echo '<img data="image2" src="imagetest.php?imagename='. $filename2 .'&height=100&width=100"/>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a mathematical way to get this job done

Github repo - https://github.com/gayanSandamal/easy-php-image-resizer

Live example - https://plugins.nayague.com/easy-php-image-resizer/

```
<?php
//path for the image
$source_url = '2018-04-01-1522613288.PNG';

//separate the file name and the extention
$source_url_parts = pathinfo($source_url);
$filename = $source_url_parts['filename'];
$extension = $source_url_parts['extension'];

//define the quality from 1 to 100
$quality = 10;

//detect the width and the height of original image
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_url);
$width;
$height;

//define any width that you want as the output. mine is 200px.
$after_width = 200;

//resize only when the original image is larger than expected with.
//this helps you to avoid from unwanted resizing.
if ($width > $after_width) {

    //get the reduced width
    $reduced_width = ($width - $after_width);
    //now convert the reduced width to a percentage and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_radio = round(($reduced_width / $width) * 100, 2);

    //ALL GOOD! let's reduce the same percentage from the height and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_height = round(($height / 100) * $reduced_radio, 2);
    //reduce the calculated height from the original height
    $after_height = $height - $reduced_height;

    //Now detect the file extension
    //if the file extension is 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG' or 'JPEG'
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'JPG' || $extension == 'JPEG') {
        //then return the image as a jpeg image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($extension == 'png' || $extension == 'PNG') {
        //then return the image as a png image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    } else {
        //show an error message if the file extension is not available
        echo 'image extension is not supporting';
    }

    //HERE YOU GO :)
    //Let's do the resize thing
    //imagescale([returned image], [width of the resized image], [height of the resized image], [quality of the resized image]);
    $imgResized = imagescale($img, $after_width, $after_height, $quality);

    //now save the resized image with a suffix called "-resized" and with its extension. 
    imagejpeg($imgResized, $filename . '-resized.'.$extension);

    //Finally frees any memory associated with image
    //**NOTE THAT THIS WONT DELETE THE IMAGE
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($imgResized);
}
?>
```